# Solve $\frac{1}{2^\theta}\sum_{k=0}^{\theta} {\theta\choose k} \delta(k)=\theta$ for $\delta$

Tags: statistics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

The following arises in unbiased estimation of a parameter for the binomial distribution, but that information is not needed for solving the question. I tried solving this by manipulating the sum to get a recursion, but failed to do so.

> Find an explicit function $\delta:\{0,1,\dots\}\to\{1,2,\dots\}$ such that the following holds for all $\theta\in\{1,2,\dots\}$:
>
> $$
>  \frac{1}{2^\theta}\sum_{k=0}^{\theta} {\theta\choose k} \delta(k)=\theta
> $$

*EDIT*

Note that the usual unbiased estimator for this binomial parameter, i.e. the function $\delta(x)=2x$ is not a solution since $\delta$ may not map to $0$. Considering $\theta = 1$ leads to $\delta(0)=\delta(1)=1$, whence considering $\theta=2$ gives that

$$
\delta(0) + 2 \delta(1) + \delta(2) = 8 \iff \delta(2)=5,
$$

and so on one may continue to find $\delta(k)$ for every $k$, but I cannot find the pattern and solve to get an explicit function.

Comment: Hint: Think about ways to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\theta} \binom{\theta}{k} = 2^\theta$, then use calculus.

Comment: Thanks @AntonioVargas, I don't quite get there. The only solution I get by that path, i.e. using binomial theorem and differentiate both sides of the identity for $(1+x)^\theta$ is $\delta(x)=2x$, but that's not a solution to the problem since $\delta$ maps to $\{1,2,\dots\}$. Is there a way forward here that you can give a further hint for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oussama Boussif,
in a truly nice use
of Pascals's inversion formula,
showed that
$\delta(k)
= 2k
$ is a solution.
However,
the OP said that
the solution must have
$\delta(k)
\in \{1, 2, ...\}
$.

To satisfy this,
use
$\sum_{k=0}^{\theta} (-1)^k \binom{\theta}{k}
= 0
$.
Therefore,
for any real $a$,
$\delta(k)
=2k+a(-1)^k
$
is a solution.

Choosing
$a = 1$
gives
$\delta(k)
=2k+(-1)^k
= 1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9, ... 
$.

If the results have to be distinct,
I would have to think some more.

Comment: No need for distinctness, this is great. Thanks

Comment: Oussama Boussif did tha hard work. Please also upvote his answer.

Comment: I wonder if one could use this as another example of how one sometimes gets a uniformly smaller mean squared error with a biased estimator.  If I'm not mistaken, the maximum-likelihood estimator is $\delta(k) = \begin{cases} 2k & \text{if }k\ne0, \\ 1 & \text{if }k=0. \end{cases}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: +1 Nice answer.But why would Pascal inversion formula return a wrong formula? Maybe there are some constraints and I dont know of

Comment: @OussamaBoussif, in this case it gives the right answer to the wrong question. The constraint is that $\delta(k)$ cannot map to $0$. 

Indeed, $a=1$ is the only value that will work for this problem as non-integer values are ruled out, negative integers will make $\delta(0)<0$ and larger positive integers will make $\delta(1)<1$. One may actually prove, and I only know how to do it using results from Statistics about uniqueness of minimum variance unbiased estimators, that this is the only possible solution to the problem.

Comment: Ah alright I got it thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let's introduce the following Pascal inversion formula:

$$
{b}_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a_k\\
a_n={(-1)}^{p}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k
{n\choose k}a_k
$$

So:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}{\theta\choose k}\delta{(k)} = {2}^{\theta}\theta
$$

Using the latter, we get:

$$
\delta{(\theta)}={(-1)}^{\theta}\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}(-1)^k
{\theta\choose k}k2^k
$$

Let's evaluate the latter sum:

We define $y$ such that:

$$
y=\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}x^k
{\theta \choose k}={(1+x)}^{\theta}\\
y'=\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}k{x}^{k-1}
{\theta \choose k}=\theta {(1+x)}^{\theta-1}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}k{x}^{k}
{\theta \choose k}=xy'=x\theta {(1+x)}^{\theta-1}
$$

Now let $x=-2$ and you'll get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\theta}k{(-2)}^{k}
{\theta\choose k}=2\theta{(-1)}^{\theta}
$$

So:

$$
\delta{(k)}=2k
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but $\delta(0)=0$ is not allowed since $\delta$ maps to $\{1,2,\dots\}$. Any easy way to fix it?

Comment: Great answrr! I added an answer that answers OP's comment.

Comment: $\delta(k)=2k$ is exactly what common sense would suggest, but whether this problem can be solved subject to the constraint that no value of $\delta$ can be $0$ is another matter. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: See my answer. "Yes it can!"